# Chrome save as PDF doesn't work

Tags: chrome-for-android, pdf

For some reason whenever I try to save a webpage as a PDF Chrome generates a 0-byte size document. And when I try to open the PDF in my Downloads folder QuickPDF tells me "Error while opening file. It appears to be damamged."
My phone is a Moto G if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively visit http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/ and paste the url which you want as a PDF.

Or

If you want to download pdf via app, try free app named "UrlToPdf" from play store.